# python multiprocessing hangs after a few iterations

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multiprocessing

I am running a `multiprocessing` pool in a for loop over a chuck of data. It runs fine for two iterations and hangs on the third. If I reduce the size of each chuck it hangs later on perhaps the forth or fifth iteration. In the program where I discovered the problem I am running a more extensive function but this works to reproduce the error.

Is there a proper way to terminate a pool after it is finished? So that I can start it again.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocess import Pool

df = pd.read_csv('paths.csv')

def do_something(user):
    v = df[df['userId'] == user]
    return v

if __name__ == '__main__':
    users = df['userId'].unique()
    n_chunks = round(len(users)/40)
    subsets = [users[i:i+n_chunks] for i in range(0, len(users), n_chunks)]
    chunk_counter = 0
    for user_subset in subsets:
        chunk_counter += 1
        print(f'Beginning to process chunk {chunk_counter}...')
        with Pool() as pool:
            frames = pool.map(do_something, user_subset)
            pool.close()
            pool.terminate()

        print(f'Completed processing chunk {chunk_counter}.')
```

Comment: Is it possible that you want to call join instead of or in addition to terminate?

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `pool.join()` following `pool.terminate()` didn't help. It still successfully completes a few iterations then hangs.

Comment: I don't know why your program hangs, but why are you defining your `Pool` within the `for` loop? You can define it outside the loop and re-use it in each iteration. That is likely to be kinder on your system resources (and may thereby solve your immediate issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to prevent the hanging with the code below:

```
with Pool(maxtasksperchild=1) as pool:
    frames = pool.map_async(do_something, user_subset).get()
    pool.terminate()
    pool.join()
```

I don't understand why using `map_async` would prevent the hanging. I will dive deeper if I have a chance and update if I understand the reason.